# In GNU screen, is it possible to programmatically read the status message?

Tags: gnu-screen

I am considering writing a graphical tool that will show you what gnu-screen sessions you have and what windows are available in them. You would then be able to, for example, click on the window title and it would take you there. I do not want to modify gnu-screen in any way so that my tool can work with existing installations on other machines and so on.

I can get ordinary output from programs running inside screen out of the screen session by using a log-file, or by copying the last few lines into the exchange-buffer. What I really need in order to make a nice user interface though is the contents of the status line (the line that temporarily appears at the bottom of the window). For example, to get the list of windows in a session I can send the `windowlist` command, but the result is never part of the output. Does anyone know if there is a way to make screen put its messages into the log, into a paste-buffer, into the current window, or anything similar where I can grab it from another program?